# Proof that a differentiable function satisfying $f'(x)f(x) = 0$ is constant

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Back again! help is much appreciate as I seem to have found myself stuck and pretty much turned in a blank worksheet to my professor. He says these types of problems will be on our final, and I have no clue where to start.

Suppose a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable everywhere and satisfies $f(x)f'(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove $f$ is constant and make sure the quantifiers in the proof are explicit.

Comment: The way you solve these problems is by writing. You will never get the answer if you just think hard and hope an idea will come. You need to see the specific expressions/equations and analyze them. This sort of fiddling occurs in all walks of mathematics, from the purest to the most applied.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Let $g(x)=f(x)^2$. What is $g'(x)$ and what does that tell about $g$?

Answer (score 2):

This is an attempt to
*not* use
$(f^2(x))'
=2f(x)f'(x)
$.

Suppose $f$
is not a constant.
Then there are
$a$ and $b$
such that
$f(a)
\ne f(b)
$.

By the mean value theorem,
there is a $c$ such that
$a \le c \le b$
and
$f'(c)
=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}
\ne 0
$.

Since
$f'(c)
\ne 0
$,
$f(c) = 0$.

In the neighborhood of $c$,
$f(c+h)
\approx f(c)+hf'(c)
=hf'(c)
$.
Similarly,
$f(c+2h)
\approx 2hf'(c)
$.
Therefore,
$\frac{f(c+2h)-f(c+h)}{h}
\approx f'(c+h)
\ne 0
$,
so,
at $x=c+h$,
neither
$f(x)$ or $f'(x)$
are $0$.

This contradicts $f(x)f'(x) = 0$.
Therefore $f$ is constant.

Note:
My use of
$f(c+h)
\approx f(c)+hf'(c)
$
means that
$f(c+h)
= f(c)+hf'(c)+o(h)
$.
This allows the implications above
to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$0 = 2f(x)f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}f^2(x)$$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/540868)

Comment: @tomi that's a pretty bizarre review. This is clearly an answer to the question. What is the reasoning behind your "not an answer" vote?

Comment: @MattSamuel I thought this would be more appropriate as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: It is a "hint" answer... we usually do this when the problem is pretty simple and the OP hasn't shown any effort in solving it